# iOS - Xcode 5 Clang Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ld, duplicate-symbol

I was making a prototype in Xcode 5 and there were a lot of error so I decided to come back to the drawing board and start a new project. When I created the new project it had a clang error just like the last one.

Here is what it says

```
Ld /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.app/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar normal i386
    cd "/Users/jaydenkelly/Desktop/Trivia in a Jar"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Intermediates/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.build/Objects-normal/i386/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Intermediates/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.build/Objects-normal/i386/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar.app/Trivia\ in\ a\ Jar

duplicate symbol _i in:
    /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Intermediates/Trivia in a Jar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia in a Jar.build/Objects-normal/i386/Game.o
    /Users/jaydenkelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trivia_in_a_Jar-cqzkvawfethhydcaldqtecmwfkkm/Build/Intermediates/Trivia in a Jar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Trivia in a Jar.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Make sure you didn't import an `.m` file.

Comment: Can you share the contents of Game.o and Test.o? You must be declaring two things named "i" in a scope where they collide.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have two global variables `_i`, one in `Game.m` and one in `Test.m` files. Just make them `static` if you don't need them to be visible in the whole program.